# Mosquitto sub client test code giving segmentation fault

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am working on mosquitto v1.4.4. I have installed this on the Raspberry Pi and the application is running well. I was trying MQTT sample programs (msgsps_sub.c) in the test folder of the tar. When I compile and run the
msgsps_sub.c program the sub client is able to connect to broker and subscribe to a topic. But when I send a message using a publisher, the above program (msgsps_sub.c) crashes with segmentation fault.

I feel the issue is in the  my_message_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *msg)
function.

The original code is:

```
    void my_message_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *msg)
    {
        if(message_count == 0){
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    }

    fwrite(msg->payload, sizeof(uint8_t), msg->payloadlen, fptr);
    message_count++;
    if(message_count == MESSAGE_COUNT){
        gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
        mosquitto_disconnect((struct mosquitto *)obj);
    }
}
```

I changed the code to:

```
void my_message_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *msg)
{   
    printf("Message Received\n");
}
```

In the first case the program crashes when a message is received from broker. In second case it successfully prints "Message received" on the console. I feel there is some issue with mosquitto_message *msg variable.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to inspect the variables in the callback? Are you certain there aren't any old versions of the mosquitto library hanging around on your system?

Comment: I had previously installed mosquitto 1.0.2 using make install. Which I could not uninstall so deleted its files from the folders where it was present. After deleting its files I installed mosquitto 1.4.4. So when I run the broker it shows version number 1.4.4. Is it possible that few files (of older version) might have remained somewhere?? I am newbie to linux.

Comment: @ralight: As you correctly suspected the old library was causing the issue. I used a different sd card installed with fresh version of raspbian and mosquitto 1.4.4. The above issue didn't appear. Subscribe program was able to read the messages from broker. Hence I feel the issue was because of a previous version of mosquitto hanging around in the setup. Thanks a lot